# Grails Criteria querying a list with ilike

Tags: grails, closures, criteria

I want to query a list in criteria like this:

```
def patterns = ["abc%", "cde%"]
def criteria = MyEntity.createCriteria();
def results = criteria.list {
  and {
    patterns.collect {
      not { ilike(name, it) }
    }
}
```

is this basically possible? What do I have to do to get this query working?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting which will create a collection of the contents you need to simply iterate.

```
def patterns = ["abc%", "cde%"]
def criteria = MyEntity.createCriteria();
def results = criteria.list {
  and {
    patterns.each {
      not { ilike('name', it) }
    }
}
```